# My simple 'if' statement isn't doing what's in the code

Tags: c++

In this little code section, I am gathering input data from the user. If the first input given is a "0" then it does not accept more information, if it is not a "0" then it prompts for the rest of the data.

```
class Molecule {

char structure[10];
char name[20];
double weight;

public:

Molecule();
bool read();
void display() const;

};

bool Molecule::read() {


cout << "Enter structure : ";
cin >> structure;

if (structure != "0") {
cout << "Enter name : ";
cin >> name;
cout << "Enter weight : ";
cin >> weight;
}
}
```

This should say, if structure is not 0, then prompt for the rest of the information. But when I run this it displays the other cout and cin even if I input 0. Why is it not doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: what's the type of structure?

Comment: Show your declaration of `structure`

Comment: i am surprised that this compiles (c maybe but c++ is usually pretty picky)

Comment: @pm100: Arrays decay to pointers so both `structure` and `"0"` are implicitly converted to `char*`, the result of such comparison is unspecified though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting a comparison on string values but you're actually doing a comparison on pointer values.  You need to use a function like `strcmp` to get value comparison semantics

```
if (strcmp(structure, "0") != 0) {
  ...
}
```

The original code you write is effectively doing the following

```
int left = structure;
int right = "0";
if (left != right) { 
  ...
}
```

I've glossed over a few details there (including architecture), but essentially that is what your original sample is doing.  C/C++ doesn't really have a notion of string values.  It has a limited understanding of string literals and how to convert them to `char` arrays, but not how the values should be understood.

Comment: or better still use std::string

Comment: I tried doing a strcmp(structure, "0") but it said "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer"

Comment: @JaredPar ah sorry I didn't update my != "0" I forgot to remove the quotes, it works now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

expanding my comment

Use

```
#include <string>

...

std::string structure;

...
structure="foo";
....
if(structure == "foo")
{
   ...
}
```